# High computer case temperature

Tags: ubuntu-mate

My computer was doing an image save of my hard drive to a second hard drive. (Clonezilla)

I have done that many times.

But I heard some unusual sounds coming from my computer case.

So I took off one of the side panels and could feel some heat that seemed uncharacteristically high.

I put a thermometer in and it read around 100 degrees F.

After the process, the temp went to around 80 degrees.

Do I need to be concerned?

Comment: install `psensors` and you can check the temperature of the CPU and GPU.

Comment: I have psensors, but it does not work when Clonezilla is running. @ Abhay Patil